# NestJS : Auth guard flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, linkedin-api, nestjs

I am implementing linkedin login strategy with passport in nestJS.
What I have right now is that I have a button "Login with linkedin" points to `auth/linkedin`.

```
@Get('auth/linkedin')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('linkedin'))
async linkedinAuth(@Req() req) {
    
}
```

Which works great and takes me to the linkedin login page and hits back my callback URL which is `auth/linkedin/callback` with `code` query string of token **and this is where I am unable to figure out what todo and how to return linkedin user**

```
@Get('auth/linkedin/callback')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('linkedin'))
linkedinCallBack(@Req() req) {
  console.log(req)
  return 'handle callback!';
}
```

Linkedin passport strategy :

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
const LinkedInAuthStrategy = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;

@Injectable()
export class LinkedinStrategy extends PassportStrategy(LinkedInAuthStrategy) {
  constructor(
  ) {
    super({
      clientID: 'abcd123',
      clientSecret: 'abcd123',
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:5000/auth/linkedin/callback',
      scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_liteprofile'],
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
        console.log(profile);
        return done(null, profile);
      });
    })
  }
}
```

*Note: I am using this [package](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2) for linkedin passport strategy*

> **Question : How can I handle callback further with `@UseGuards`, and return LinkedIn user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this article: [OAuth2 in NestJS for Social Login (Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc)](https://csaba-apagyi.medium.com/oauth2-in-nestjs-for-social-login-google-facebook-twitter-etc-8b405d570fd2) and this repo: https://github.com/thisismydesign/nestjs-starter

In the `validate` method of `LinkedinStrategy` you need to find or create the user (probably store in your DB), e.g.:

```js
export class LinkedinStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  // constructor...

  async validate(accessToken, refreshToken, profile) {
    let user = await this.usersService.findOneByProvider('linkedin', profile.id);
    if (!user) {
      user = await this.usersService.create({
        provider: 'linkedin',
        providerId: id,
        name: profile.name,
        username: profile.email,
      });
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

In the controller's callback endpoint you can issue a JWT token to handle the User's session within the app:

```js
@Get('auth/linkedin/callback')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('linkedin'))
linkedinCallBack(@Req() req) {
  const { accessToken } = this.jwtAuthService.login(req.user);
  res.cookie('jwt', accessToken);
  return res.redirect('/profile');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should adapt the `LinkedinStrategy` class a bit. You can't use the `done` function directly. It will be called by nest. You should have a `validate` method and return a user object from it. That object will be set to the request object so in the controller you will be able to access it with `req.user`. This is approximately how your class should look:

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-linkedin-oauth2';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LinkedinStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({
        clientID: 'abcd123',
        clientSecret: 'abcd123',
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:5000/auth/linkedin/callback',
        scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_liteprofile'],
      });
  }

  async validate(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: object): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(profile);

    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: makes sense, but how can i handle the callback URL `auth/linkedin/callback` ?

Comment: The logic of the `validate` method will run only in the callback case. In the first case, nest will redirect to a linkedin page before `validate` is called. So you can handle the callback either in the validate method or in the controller. Again, whatever you return from the validate method will be accessable from `req.user`.

Comment: I have different purposed login pages...Is there a way tag some custom parameter when redirect to linkedin page, so after callback, it can be kept and used?